# Flash messages not working on redirect after setting up Multiple Devise User Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I implemented this solution 
[How to Setup Multiple Devise User Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)

However the devise flash messages are not working after that ,I have tried reemoving this line 
flash.clear but still the flash messages are not being displayed ,

```
# ../controllers/concerns/accessible.rb
module Accessible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
  before_action :check_user
end

protected
def check_user
 flash.clear
if current_tenant

  redirect_to(authenticated_tenant_root_path) && return
   elsif current_user

  redirect_to(authenticated_user_root_path) && return
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change your Devise localization ? It's possible that you don't have appropriate keys for your models. It should be something like this:

```
en:
 devise:
  failure:
   user:
    invalid: 'Welcome user, you are signed in.'
    not_found: 'User not found.'
  admin:
    invalid: 'Invalid admin credentials'
    not_found: 'Admin not found'
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

The devise stored_location_for fixed it for me ,found the instance method here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/StoreLocation

```
module Accessible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
   before_action :check_user
  end

  protected
   def check_user
    if current_tenant
      redirect_to stored_location_for(:tenant) || 
 authenticated_tenant_root_url && return
    elsif current_user
     redirect_to stored_location_for(:user) || 
   authenticated_user_root_url && return
   end
  end
end
```